# How to add ppa repositories?

Tags: ppa, repository, launchpad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)

I always like to have my programs up to date but in ubuntu software center the software aren't always up to date.
I know about repositorys and i'd like to add some so how can i find the repository of certain programs in launchpad.
I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.1.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific please? Name some of the programs you want to receive via a PPA.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can add a PPA location with the command

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:<ppa_name>
```

For example `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome-desktop`

You can find some help on [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/add-apt-repository)

Comment: Although there is no real 'root' user on Ubuntu, you have to have superuser permissions to add a PPA. On a regular system you have to do it with sudo: sudo add-apt-repository ...

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect that. Thanks for the informations

Comment: And if you're sure the PPA name is typed correctly, you can add ' -y' to the end to auto-allow the new PPA. (sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome-desktop -y). This makes it easier to use post-installation scripts that add multiple PPAs without user intervention.

Comment: Just curious what would happen if you accidentally added the same ppa twice?

Comment: @puk Never tried it, but considering [UbuntuForums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1250564) it gives you a warning "W: Duplicate sources.list entry"

Comment: @puk : I know this post is old but I tried it. It did not coplained and added a duplicate line in my list of software sources. I tried it with: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:freefilesync/ffs`   ..... It reported zero error, correct keyring (priv and pub) creation,etc... Exited normally. At the end I was left with a repeated line:  http://ppa.launchedpad.net/freefilesync/ffs/ubuntu trusty main (Source Code)

Comment: To use this command, I am asked to install `software-properties-common`. After I try to install it, I see that is 10.5MB in total! That's some serious size of binaries to simply add a URL to a list of URLs! :O