# Failing to fetch some packages in update

Tags: 12.04, updates, ruby, rails

I want to get ruby on rails on ubuntu 12.04 but I'm coming across errors that say I need to to update.  I've copied the result of the end of update and not included the earlier part.  I can add that if it is needed.

```
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en
Fetched 2,916 kB in 4s (663 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/opencv2/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/opencv2/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/opencv2/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

When I run rvm requirements this is the error I'm seeing.

```
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Installing requirements for ubuntu.
Updating system..................
Error running 'requirements_debian_update_system ',
showing last 15 lines of /home/charles/.rvm/log/1397254493/update_system.log
+ case "${TERM:-dumb}" in
+ case "$1" in
+ [[ -t 2 ]]
+ return 1
+ printf %b 'There has been error while updating '\''apt-get'\'', please give it some time and try again later.
For 404 errors check your sources configured in:
    /etc/apt/sources.list
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
\n'
There has been error while updating 'apt-get', please give it some time and try again later.
For 404 errors check your sources configured in:
    /etc/apt/sources.list
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list

+ return 100
Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

I'm following the instructions from 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm

Comment: Your ppa are miscongiured, a 404 error is "not found", check the ppa.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: How did you add the ppa in the first place ? http://askubuntu.com/questions/217179/how-to-add-ppa-repositories

Comment: I looked at the link but it really only added more questions.  There isn't a ppa listed in the link I was using.  Maybe I need a different install guide?

Comment: Your problem "W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gijzelaar/opencv2/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found" is because you have not configured the ppa you are using properly or the ppa is no longer maintained. What ppa is this ? This message is unrelated to your install guide.

Comment: I can see how to add a ppa from the first answer to the duplicate question link from the link you provided but I did not go through that before but it wasn't listed.  I'll keep reading on ppa's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This PPA was renamed at some point, and might actually be an issue with Launchpad. It's possible that browser hits redirect but files do not.

Currently, the "opencv2" repo redirects to "opencv2.2". 2.4 is actually more current. If you wanted 2.2, it's possible the repo is "dead" because of this. This will install 2.4.

- Remove the PPA

sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:gijzelaar/opencv2

- Install the direct PPA

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gijzelaar/opencv2.4 -y

- Update your sources

sudo apt-get update

- Retry your command.