# How do I install mdm on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, mdm

I cannot find a ppa that will install mdm on my laptop. Can anyone give a ppa and also tell me how to configure it? Because when I typed:

> sudo apt-get install mdm

and

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure mdm

there was no output!
thank you people

Comment: can you append the output of `apt-cache policy mdm` in your question?

Comment: Here is it: mdm:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.6.0-a~trusty~NoobsLab.com
  Version table:
     1.6.0-a~trusty~NoobsLab.com 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/mint/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     0.1.3-2.1 0
        500 http://mirror.dhakacom.com/ubuntu-archive/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages

Comment: Your system has the ppa repository installed, did you run `sudo apt-get update` before you attempted to install mdm?

Answer (score 3):

Earlier , there was no ppa for mdm to install it in ubuntu 14+ version and recently noobslab came up with that. If you dont have time to compile it from the source , please follow the below installation procedures in the terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/mint
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mdm mdm-themes
```

mdm-themes will have around 63 MB to download. so if are bandwidth less, please avoid mdm-themes but they are a great deal to install it. While installing the screen will reconfigure the Display Manager for you to choose. There you may choose mdm and reboot. On reboot you will see mdm but there for the first time you should select a session which is important.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the ppa: [How to add ppa repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217179/how-to-add-ppa-repositories)

Then you might want to try this one: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mdm

Comment: But how do i install ti using this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're alluding to the Mint Display Manager?

As in: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/05/how-to-install-mdm-125-from-linux-mint.html

If yes, it doesn't seem to be available for Ubuntu 14+, and in that case, your best bet is to compile MDM from source. The source is available here:
https://github.com/linuxmint/mdm

Installation instructions are not up-to-date. I might post a brief guide in this thread if the compilation proves successful and stable for me.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, beware that Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 contain a packet
mdm   (The Middleman System)
Utilities for single-host parallel shell scripting

If that's the installed packet, "there is no output" as Jatin says.

In order to have  dpkg-reconfigure mdm  choose the mdm display manager,
first configure the repository   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/mint
before installing mdm.
Fortunately, the mdm's version 1.x or 2.x is higher than Middleman's 0.x
and the latter will be hidden by the first one.