# Nvidea Driver Update Problem

Tags: drivers

I'm having problems with poor performance with one of my games using Wine. I think it may be my graphics. So I want to update to the latest driver. However, I can't seem to do it. According to this link http://www.nvidia.co.uk/download/driverResults.aspx/92854/en-uk the latest driver is 352.55.

But when running the series of commands below, it doesn't update to that version. It just stays on 352.21 (checked by going to the System Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers tab).

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
```

Why is it not updating?

Comment: Question 1: What error messages (if any) do you get when you attempt to update?  It might be that you have the most up-to-date drivers in the repository already.  Question 2: Why are you so certain it's a graphics problem?  It could be that the application you are loading through Wine is the issue...not every program is fully supported.  Looking it up on the WineDB might lead to another answer.

Comment: I doubt it has anything to do with my graphics, but you may want to try another PPA: https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa.

Comment: Yes it's a game called Eve Online, and it's in the WineDB. When it loads and I start playing the game, the process Exefile.exe spikes to like 103% and pretty much stays that way a lot of the time. There are no error messages when updating. Only that I have the latest version.

Comment: @mikewhatever, upon updating my sources.list file with the two deb lines of code they say to use, it then causes me a GPG error saying NO_PUBKEY FCAE110B1118213C

Comment: Here is how to add PPAs correctly: https://askubuntu.com/questions/217179/how-to-add-ppa-repositories.

Comment: `add-apt-repository -r` is supposed to *remove* a PPA. Is that what you intended to do?

Answer (score 1):

You used the wrong PPA - the drivers moved from xorg-edgers to Proprietary GPU Drivers PPA.

Before you install new drivers remove every NVIDIA related software and external repositories.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Now install NVIDIA 352.55 drivers - (latest stable version as of date writing these instructions) ...

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo reboot
```

If you want to install the latest official NVIDIA drivers 355.11 ... installation command would be :

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-355
```

In case you have a switchable graphics solution install NVIDIA Optimus support as well - execute :

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime
```