# manage PPA via terminal

Tags: 14.04, command-line, ppa, repository

I was searching for a way to manage my repositories in an *advanced* way and I found [y-ppa-manager](https://pkgs.org/ubuntu-12.04/getdeb-apps-i386/y-ppa-manager_0.0.9.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb.html) GUI application. it is a great application, ***that's for sure***. But is there a way to manage them via *terminal?

Like **backup** current repos to some kind of file, **restoring** them from a file. Other words is there a smiler application to [**y-ppa-manager**](https://pkgs.org/ubuntu-12.04/getdeb-apps-i386/y-ppa-manager_0.0.9.1-1~getdeb1_all.deb.html) on terminal?

Comment: What do you mean by "manage my repositories"? You can add or remove a repository form a terminal. Is that the question?

Comment: yes that's the question, have i to edit the it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can PPAs be removed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)

Comment: And http://askubuntu.com/questions/217179/how-to-add-ppa-repositories

Comment: And http://askubuntu.com/questions/28644/how-can-i-backup-my-ppas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a repository by `add-apt-repostory` command, e.g.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
```

You can remove a repository by `add-apt-repostory -r`, e.g.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
```

You can also purge all packages installed from a repository by `ppa-purge`. You will need to install it first

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

Then use it this way

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
```

The command will purge all the packages and revert them to the previous ones from the standard repos, if anything has been upgraded from the PPA.

To backup repository lists you can backup the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory. The lists are stored there.

Comment: first thank for your answer, but i'm searching for some features like back-upping, restoring..

Comment: Backuping, restoring what?

Comment: the list of ppa's

Comment: It is not very clear. Can you elaborate your question by editing the QUESTION.

Comment: @010010001 I added a backup tip.